# Gstreamer video latency first image

Tags: video, gstreamer, rtsp, latency, gstreamer-1.0

i have take the example 4 of gstreamer [link](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-docs/tree/master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-4) and adapt for recieve a video stream rtsp from a camera. I have add these changes:

```
  g_object_set(data->pipeline,"latency",0,NULL);
  g_object_set(data->pipeline,"autovideosink", NULL);
  g_object_set (data->pipeline, "ring-buffer-max-size", (guint64) 1024 * 50, NULL);
```

at the function gst_native_set_uri in the file tutorial-4.c for reduce the video latency.
My problem is that for view the video stream the first time i have to wait 2-3sec when i press the start button. There is a way to reduce this time?

Thanks

Comment: I can't see any file tutorial-4.c from the link you've provided (seems rather java code). Probably your problem is that you are setting properties to pipeline instead of its plugins. `latency` is a property of rtpjitterbuffer, or rtspsrc. autovideosink is a plugin, not sure there is a plugin having such property.

Comment: Hello, here the file https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-docs/blob/master/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-4/jni/tutorial-4.c

Comment: have you been able to try this ? Please consider I have taken some time for helping you as you've publicly asked for some help, so any feedback would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding this callback function before app_function:

```
static void source_setup (GstElement *pipeline, GstElement *source, void* unused_data) {
    gchar* source_path = gst_object_get_path_string(GST_OBJECT_CAST(source));
    if (!strcmp(source_path, "/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source")) {
        g_object_set(GST_OBJECT_CAST(source), "latency", 0, NULL);
    }
    g_free(source_path);
}
```

And in app_function, just after pipeline creation add:

```
g_signal_connect (data->pipeline, "source-setup", G_CALLBACK (source_setup), NULL);
```

When a source will be created, this callback would set its latency to 0 if the path matches playbin0/uridecodebin0/rtspsrc0 that should be ok for your case. This might be refined for more complex cases, though. Not tested with java.